# How do I store a duplicate value from an array or hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, hash, duplicates

Let's make this very easy. What I want:

```
@array = qw/one two one/;
my @duplicates = duplicate(@array);
print "@duplicates"; # This should now print 'one'.
```

How to print duplicate values of a array/hash?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish, can you clarify?

Comment: Everyone want's to remove duplicate values from a array/hash, and that's fine. But I want to KEEP that duplicate value...

Comment: @Robert Gamble: it's not clear exactly what you find not clear, can you clarify? :)

Comment: @Ysth: the question was edited to make it clear ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sub duplicate {
    my @args = @_;
    my %items;
    for my $element(@args) {
        $items{$element}++;
    }
    return grep {$items{$_} > 1} keys %items;
}
```

Comment: I think there is a semicolon missing after the hash declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The extra verbose, extra readable version of what you want to do:

```
sub duplicate {
   my %value_hash;
   foreach my $val (@_) {
     $value_hash{$val} +=1;
   }
   my @arr;
   while (my ($val, $num) = each(%value_hash)) {
     if ($num > 1) {
        push(@arr, $val)
     }
   }
  return @arr;
}
```

This can be shortened considerably, but I intentionally left it verbose so that you can follow along.

I didn't test it, though, so watch out for my typos.

Comment: @array = qw/one two one/ is a _perfectly_ acceptable way of writing that.

Comment: I wrote that before Brian D Foy fixed up the original question.  He had scalars there originally.. but I've now removed the "first off" comment, since it no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
# assumes inputs can be hash keys
@a = (1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5);

# keep count for each unique input
%h = ();
map { $h{$_}++  } @a;

# duplicate inputs have count > 1
@dupes = grep { $h{$_} > 1 } keys %h;

# should print 3, 4
print join(", ", sort @dupes), "\n";
```

Comment: Write `$h{$_}++ for @a;` instead of using `map` in void context.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary, put the value in the key, and the count in the value.

Ah, just noticed you've tagged as perl

```
while ([...]) {
 $hash{[dbvalue]}++
}
```

Comment: Eh... it's starting to get a little late, I really think I need som code examples. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unspecified in the question is the order in which the duplicates should be returned.

I can think of several possibilities: don't care; by order of first/second/last occurrence in the input list; sorted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going golfing!

```
sub duplicate {
    my %count;
    grep $count{$_}++, @_;
}

@array = qw/one two one/;
my @duplicates = duplicate(@array);
print "@duplicates"; # This should now print 'one'.

# or if returning *exactly* 1 occurrence of each duplicated item is important
sub duplicate {
    my %count;
    grep ++$count{$_} == 2, @_;
}
```

Comment: That code has an issue in that it will return an element more than once when it occurs three or more times.

Comment: Also, you want to put braces around that.

Comment: It depends on whether you want 2 of 3 occurrances returned, or only 1; the question didn't specify.  Braces aren't needed.